# Remove Data from Variable if Input Fields contain Placeholder text

Tags: php, forms, validation, foreach

I'm using the following code to validate a **'set' of input fields**. 4 fields per set (width/height/length/weight). **If a set of my input fields are empty** then it won't display that row of data in my final **$all variable**.

Here is a previous topic on the subject: [Removing Data from Variable if Input Fields incomplete - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644383/removing-data-from-variable-if-input-fields-incomplete-php) - this works great.

**However**, this time I am using "Placeholder" text (input field *value* attribute) and therefore I need my PHP to check whether that placeholder value exists.

**Here is my Pseudo Code, however I'm unsure how to achieve with regular PHP:**

```
if ((pNUM-VALUEheight = "Height (cm)" OR pNUM-VALUEwidth = "Width (cm)" OR pNUM-VALUElength = "Length (cm)" OR pNUM-VALUEweight = "Weight (kg)"))
Then 
// Don't store in $all variable
Else
// Do store set of values in $all variable
End If
```

**Here is my current PHP code:**

```
    ...
    $ierrors = array();
    $all = '';

    // Loop over the values 1 through 20
    foreach( range( 1, 20) as $i)
    {
        // Create an array that stores all of the values for the current number
        $values = array( 
            'p' . $i . 'height' => $_POST['p' . $i . 'height'], 
            'p' . $i . 'width' => $_POST['p' . $i . 'width'], 
            'p' . $i . 'length' => $_POST['p' . $i . 'length'], 
            'p' . $i . 'weight' => $_POST['p' . $i . 'weight']
        );

        // Assume all values are empty.
        $allEmpty = true;

        // Validate every value
        foreach( $values as $key => $value)
        {
            if( empty($value))
                $ierrors[] = "Value $key is not set";
            else
                $allEmpty = false;


            // You can add more validation in here, such as:
            if( !is_numeric( $value) ) 
                $ierrors[] = "Value $key contains an invalid value '$value'";
        }

        // Join all of the values together to produce the desired output
        if (!$allEmpty)
            $all .= implode( '|', $values) . "\n\n";
    }
    ...
```

Many thanks for any pointers here or please let me know if any clarity is needed.

Thank you

Comment: >> http://jsfiddle.net/bj8Ua/1/ Although this example doesn't work in JSFiddle, this is a snippet of my current HTML and JS code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using jQuery, I'd use a bit of JavaScript to clear the input fields on submit:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function() {
        var domElement = $(this).get(0);
        if (domElement.value == domElement.defaultValue) {
            domElement.value = '';
        }
    });
});
```

Watch out for typos, didn't test.

You can then check in your PHP file for empty strings and don't have to explicitly state all the possible values (they might change slightly, after all):
    if ($_POST['inputName'] == '')

OR

you could use a simple for loop:

```
for ($i = 0, $numFields = 20; $i <= $numFields; ++$i) {
    if ($_POST['p' . $i . 'width'] != 'Width (cm)' && $_POST['p' . $i . 'height'] != 'Height (cm)') {
        // add row to table
    }
}
```

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that. Very good thinking :-) Hold on while I try this out...

Comment: Should the 'form' part on line 1 be replaced with my form id/name?

Comment: I should have mentioned, I am using: http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/ to generate the placeholder values so they aren't actually stored in the value="" attribute. Does this complicate matters?

Comment: Yes, you can change it to your form's id if you want, the above is general for all forms on the page. The watermark plugin shouldn't be a problem. I don't know the plugin but you're already using defaultValue in your onBlur and onFocus, so it should hold the correct values.

Comment: OK. I'll have a think about how best to do this. I'm just a bit confused by it is all. My PHP is checking for empty strings. Should the above JS clear my fields that store the watermark text?

Comment: Thanks for the update, really appreciate your help. Will give it a try shortly.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing something like this with your HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="length[]">
<input type="text" name="width[]">
```

Then you can do something like this in PHP:

```
if(array_keys($_POST['length']) != array_keys($_POST['width']))
{
    // Incomplete post
}

$all_keys = array_merge(array_keys($_POST['length']), array_keys($_POST['width']));

foreach($all_keys as $curr_key)
{
    // $_POST['length'][$curr_key]
    // $_POST['width'][$curr_key]
}
```

While using JS is good to validate information from the client before submission.  You should always check your values server side as well.